# Copy Photoshop effects across documents to another layer?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs6, photoshop-effects

How can I copy effects from layer A in document A to layer B in document B without having to copy the entire layer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right click layer with the effect you wish to copy, select <kbd>Copy Layer Style</kbd>, right click the layer you want to transfer the effect to and choose <kbd>Paste Layer Style</kbd>.